# Laravel DB Connection to a separate connection works locally but doesn't inside server

Tags: mysql, laravel, pdo

I am trying to connect a second database in a separate server to my Laravel app and currently I can't get a connection to it. I am able to connect to the database normally through my local environment when I type `DB::connection('connection')->table('users')->get()` inside of `php artisan tinker`.
But when I try the same when I ssh into my server to test the connection I get a connection timeout.

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection timed out (SQL: select * from 
>   `users`)'

Here are my connection settings:

```
'connection' => [
    'driver' => 'mysql',
    'host' => env('DB_HOST_TWO', '127.0.0.1'),
    'port' => env('DB_PORT_TWO', '3306'),
    'database' => env('DB_DATABASE_TWO', ''),
    'username' => env('DB_USERNAME_TWO', ''),
    'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD_TWO', ''),
    'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
    'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
    'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
    'prefix' => '',
    'strict' => true,
    'engine' => null,
],
```

I verified with my environmental variables, both local and in the server they have the same credentials

Comment: Is your *host* variable *localhost* or *127.0.0.1* or real IP of the server (on the remote server itself)? Is your database running on the remote server? Did you configure it yourself? Also look for "binding" it may be bound only to the socket or check for configuration of `--bind-address`. Can you connect to the mysql on remote server via mysql client on the server itself? `mysql -h localhost -u root -p`?

Comment: Host variable is the server's IP address. Bind address is set to `*`. I can't connect using `mysql -h ip -u user -p` but I am able to connect to it using mysql workbench using a ssh-tunel. Do I have to set my binding address to my server's IP? I think it's weird I am able to connect locally but not in a server

Comment: *I think it's weird I am able to connect locally but not in a server* are you sure that you are not logging in to your local development machine instead? Are you on Windows? On the remote server is mysql process running? Try `sudo lsof -i:3306` or `ps -aux | grep mysql`

Comment: if you can't connect from local but you can connect via an ssh tunnel and your bind address is * then also check whether the remote server is blocking direct connections to the mysql port via a firewall or something like that

Comment: I am on a local ubuntu environment `mysqld  1748 mysql   27u  IPv4  31304      0t0  TCP localhost:mysql (LISTEN)`

Comment: @apokryfos I can connect to it locally, just in the server I am having issues

Comment: you mentioned that *I can't connect using mysql -h ip -u user -p but I am able to connect to it using mysql workbench using a ssh-tunel* but now you are saying you can connect from local. Which one is it?

Comment: Wait a second; you have 2 environments; *local* and lets call it *staging* (whatever is out there in the internet). Are you running the mysql database on both environments?

Comment: @Kyslik Yes on both environments, sorry for the confusion. I should clarify I am able to get a connection using Laravel's command line on my _local_ environment but not my _staging_ environment

Comment: Ok, good; so obviously you need to confirm that mysql is running on the *staging* environment; I do not care about your *local* ubuntu env; its working [there, right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53416238/laravel-db-connection-works-locally-but-doesnt-inside-server?noredirect=1#comment93707757_53416238)?

Comment: @Kyslik mysql is being ran on the staging server

Comment: Ok, now you need to be able to log in to it right? Have you created same user / password for the database? How did you confirm that?

Comment: I am able to log into normally, yes. It's a different user/password combo from the environmental file since it's a different connection. Confirmed by using `mysql -u user -p`

Comment: So in the *staging* .env change the IP for `localhost`. And bust cache `php artisan config:clear`. Because obviously if you run `mysql -u user -p` (you do not specify `-h`), `-h` default is `localhost`.

Comment: I get denied access, the second database is in a different server. It wouldn't make sense for it to be accessed locally.

Comment: *Confirmed by using `mysql -u user -p`* :D so what did you confirm with this? Obviously the problem is that you can not reach the *staging* server or *port* is blocked; and when you use ssh-tunnel (in workbench) it uses `localhost` instead of public IP of the server. So you need to figure out how to reach the *staging* server in a first place. Google around the error message `connection timed-out`.

Comment: The port wasn't open for the staging server I feel like an idiot now, thank you for your help @Kyslik

Comment: Just delete the question and pretend it never happened ;)